# Having an issue computing a value from a method that I've created that uses a formula

Tags: java, math, methods, formula

I'm making a class and I'm trying to create a method that takes time as a parameter and does this formula to find the distance of something:

```
d(t) = vt cosθ
```

where d(t) is distance, v is velocity, t is time, and θ is the angle in degrees.

This is how I wrote it out in Java and then I tested it but didn't get the right result.

If I calculate distance with these values: velocity = 21 time = 43 angle = 62 I get a result of 423.93, but if I put it in my test class and use the method (and put in the same values) I get 487.89.

What did I do wrong? Why am I getting this value?

Method:

```
public double getDistance(double time) {
    double vt = velocity * time;
    angle = (int) Math.toRadians(angle);
    double cosineCalc =  Math.cos(angle);
    double distance = vt * cosineCalc;
    return distance;
```

Tester class implementation:

```
Projectile testOne = new Projectile(21, 62);
double actual = testOne.getDistance(43);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `(int) Math.toRadians(angle)` loses precision and ends up rounding it to an integer. To make it work, make sure that `angle` is kept as a `double` and remove the `(int)` cast.

Comment: shit you're right... now I just need to ask my professor why he's making me put angle as an int... thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

```
angle = (int) Math.toRadians(angle);
```

remove the (int) casting and it should work.